# Play framework get form value

Tags: html, forms, playframework-1.x

I have a form with an accept button and a reject button.  When a user presses the accept button I want the value of accepted in my database to contain the value true.  If the user presses reject then I want the value of accepted in my database to contain the value false.  The code I have below does not work.  Are there any suggestions on how I can get this working properly?

```
public static void acceptOrRejectResponseForm(Long id,String accept,String reject) {

      Response responseForm = Response.findById(id);

      if(accept != null && !accept.isEmpty()){
          responseForm.accepted = true;
      }
      else if(reject != null && !reject.isEmpty()){
          responseForm.accepted = false;
      }
      accepted.save();
}
```

This my html

```
<form action="@Admin.acceptOrRejectResponseForm(response.id)" method="GET">                      
   <input type="submit" value="accept"  name="accept">
   <input type="submit" value="reject"  name="reject">
```

Comment: You should describe the problem better instead of just saying "it doesn't work". Is there a typo in the function (`accepted.save();`)? What object is `accepted`?

Comment: accepted is boolean inside my Response model

Comment: the error is the program do not recognize 'accepted'. however, I defined it.

Answer (score 0):

don`t create two submit buttons.

Create two hidden fields with default value 0. Call name accept and reject. Than create two buttons with onclick action. If you click on accept button with the onclick action you just set the hidden field accept on 1 and reject on 0. When you click reject button you set hidden accept field on 0 and reject on 1. Than you make submit for the form in js. In the code get those two fields and check witch one is set for 1 and witch one is set to 0. That way you can set it in db

Comment: How to do it as I am new in computing I dont understand what do you mean exactly

Comment: @lina how to do what ? You have form with two buttons (type="button"). Each butto has onclick action. You set the hidden inputs values in the javascript action. After setting them in same action you submit form with javascript submit() function

Comment: yes, but mine I have not any javascript function as i dont know how to use it in Play framework.I use the above form in my template and the action is my controller.I think , i confused everything

Comment: @lina add javascript to your template. Javascript is part of normal template so it doesn`t matter if u use play, spring or what ever. Simple script in your template